# Webworker vs node environment

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-worker

How do I tell the difference between webworker and a node environment? Neither of them have a `window`. They appear similar as a result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 if(module) console.log("node");
```

As far as i know, web workers don't have modules. There are probably a lot of other globals that are only available in node, `require` for example, or `__dirname` , [here is a complete list](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html).